# No puedo ejecutar Jquery despues de hacer un load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Luego de incluir un archivo .html dentro de un div mediante un load, deja de ejecutarse el codigo jquery. Alguien sabe el porque pasa esto y como solucionarlo?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var pathHtml = "src/html/";
  var left = pathHtml + "left/";

  function loadPage(section, page){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(section).html("<div class='loader'></div>");
        },
        success: function(){
            $(section).load(page + ".html");
        }
    });
  };

  $("#wall").load(left + "wall.html");
  $("#url, .font-strong").click(function(){
    loadPage("#left", left + "profile");
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿podrías agregar tu código a la pregunta haciendo clic en el boton editar? Gracias!

Comment: Hola. bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye el código que has escrito y que te da el problema. De lo contrario es imposible reproducirlo y ayudarte.

Comment: Puedes enseñarnos lo que te marca la consola del navegador clic derecho -> inspeccionar elemento--->consola

Comment: No muestra nada. Para especificar el problema: Tengo 3 columnas (3 div). Cuando ejecuto un elemento html que se muestra mediante un load, el jquery no me ejecuta. pero desde otro elemento html que no traje mediante un load si lo ejecuta

Comment: @garyeikoow revisa la pestaña del inspector que se llama network  y fijate como haces la petición, porque lo que veo en el ajax, no le envías a nadie (url) algo?¿ No se que quieras enviar mediante ajax :S

Comment: @Irwing Pienso hacer toda la web tipo App, trabajando con atributos data de elementos html y no mediante GET's. el .html llamado mediante el load no me trae nada desde network. Es como si pasara que cuando se hace un load html ya no reconociera el archivo .js donde tengo el jquery

Comment: @garyeikoow perfecto, ten en cuenta que siempre hay algo que recibimos en el ajax, en la función success, algún dato.. o algo. No veo donde recibes ese valor, por ejemplo success: function(result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no entiendo porque necesitas `$.ajax()` y dentro de esta un `.load()`, pero yo cambiaría esa forma de llamar al método de esta manera:

```
$("#url, .font-strong").click(function(){
  $("#left").html("<div class='loader'></div>");
  $.get(left + "profile", function(data) {
    $("#left").html(data);
  });
});
```

Así te olvidas del método, donde `data` es la página `HTML`, también verifica que dentro de ese `html` no haya una instancia de `jQuery` esto tendría conflicto con la librería.